# Need to create multile vms in azure through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm facing issues during creation of multiple VMs in Azure with Terraform.
Each time it is failing because it is picking the same network-interface-id. So how can I change my Terraform code to make this use the different network interfaces?

Here is my Terraform file:

```
variable "node_count" {default = 2} 

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "terraform-CnetFace" {
  name = "cacctni-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
  location = "East US 2"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraform-test.name}"

  ip_configuration {
      name = "cIpconfig-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
      subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.terraform-test.id}"
      private_ip_address_allocation = "dynamic"
  }
  count = "${var.node_count}"
}

variable "confignode_count" {default = 2} 

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "terraform-test" {
  name   = "confignode-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
  location = "East US 2"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.terraform-test.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.terraform-CnetFace.id}"]
  vm_size = "Standard_A0"
  availability_set_id = "${azurerm_availability_set.terraform-test.id}"

  storage_image_reference {
      publisher = "Canonical"
      offer = "UbuntuServer"
      sku = "14.04.2-LTS"
      version = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
      name = "configosdisk-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
      vhd_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.terraform-test.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.terraform-test.name}/configosdisk-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}.vhd"
      caching = "ReadWrite"
      create_option = "FromImage"
  }

  storage_data_disk {
  name          = "configdatadisk-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
  vhd_uri       = "${azurerm_storage_account.terraform-test.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.terraform-test.name}/configdatadisk-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}.vhd"
  disk_size_gb  = "512"
  create_option = "empty"
  lun           = 0
  }

  os_profile {
      computer_name = "confignode-${format("%02d", count.index+1)}"
      admin_username = "ubuntu"
      admin_password = "Qawzsx12345"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
      disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  tags {
      environment = "Production"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sleep 30"
  }

  #Loop for Count
  count = "${var.confignode_count}"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to link two resources as you loop through them then you need to use "splats" to retrieve the list of resources created in a loop and select the right one. This is explained briefly in the [interpolation syntax docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#element_list_index_) and the [resources docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html).

In your case you probably want something like:

```
variable "count" {default = 2} 

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "terraform-CnetFace" {
  count = "${var.count}"
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "terraform-test" {
  count = "${var.count}"
  ...
  network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.terraform-CnetFace.*.id, count.index)}"]
  ...
}
```

This exposes the outputs for each of the looped network interfaces created and then loops through them grabbing the `id` from the output and passing it to the appropriate `azurerm_virtual_machine`.